# Show that the set of absolutely summable real valued sequences is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that the set of real valued sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum |x_n|$ is finite, is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

I need to show that the set of all absolutely convergent series belong to the Borel Algebra $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$.

I tried to show that the sequence of the partial sums belong to the borel algebra. I already know that the set of convergent sequences belongs to the algebra and therefore the sequence of partial sums (i.e.$\{S_1,S_2,...\} $ where $S_k = \sum\limits^k_{n=1}X_n$ is a convergent sequence and so it belongs to the borel Algebra.

Unfortunatedly this doesn't mean that the set of the terms of this series belongs to the algebra so this idea won't give me the result I need.

Any tips?

Comment: When you say "the Borel algebra" you are implicitly assuming there is a topology. What topology are you using?

Comment: The box topology and the product topology yield the same Borel algebra. Can't think of another candidate. @User8128

Comment: @ThomasAndrews good point! Looking back, I'm not quite sure why I asked

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is endowed with the product topology and $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. Then for each $M$ and $n$, the set

$$ E_{M,n} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_k| \leq M \right\}$$

is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and hence is Borel-measurable. Now notice that

$$ \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| < \infty \right\}
= \bigcup_{M=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{M,n}. $$

Can you conclude that the LHS is also Borel-measurable?

---

*Remark.* A more transparent version of the above argument is as follows: Consider the sequence of functions $F_n : \mathbb{R}^{\infty} \to [0,\infty]$ defined by

$$ F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_k|. $$

Then each $F_n$ is continuous and hence Borel-measurable. Then its supremum

$$ F(x) = \sup_{n\geq 1}F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| $$

is also Borel-measurable. Now

$$ \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| < \infty \right\} = F^{-1}([0,\infty)) $$

is the inverse image a Borel subset $[0,\infty) \in \mathscr{B}([0,\infty])$ under a Borel-measurable map, hence is also Borel-measurable.

Comment: Ah, you edited it while I was writing the remark about continuity :) +1 Anyway